# Renamed deep link URL doesn't open my updated iOS app any more

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I've been using Branch.io for deep linking purposes. Recently, we've been required to change the URL. So, I've created a new app and added the API keys, domains in the Associated Domains/entitlements section in my Xcode project.

Strangely, now the new URL doesn't open the app and takes it to the browser only.

Am I missing something? Or updating the associated domains incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, toggling the associated domains capability from the identifiers section in developer.apple.com made it work!